# Addin extra properties to MembershipProvider

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using SqlMemberShipProvider and it works well, but I wish that the MembershipUser had some additional properties such as FirstName, LastName, Phone Number, etc. What is the best way to go about this? Do I have to create a custom membership provider or is there a better way to add additional functionality to users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additional information about a user is exactly what the [ProfileProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) is for. You can specify in the web.config file what extra properties you want and the default provider ([SqlProfileProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx) if you're going to keep with your current use of SQL) will handle the persistence for you.

Here's a link for [how to build the sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zs47k7y.aspx).